# Where can I get full (if not possible some selected) Samveda chants

Tags: vedas, sama-veda, purusha, vedic-chanting

Saamveda is really a [delight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJJvr1nvs6Y) to hear. That's why Bhagwan Shri Krishna says

> वेदानां सामवेदोऽस्मि देवानामस्मि वासवः।
>
> इन्द्रियाणां मनश्चास्मि भूतानामस्मि चेतना॥१०.२२॥
>
> Of the Vedas I am the Sama Veda; of the gods I am Indra, the king of heaven; of the senses I am the mind; and in living beings I am the living force [consciousness]. [BG 10.22](http://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-10-22/)

Really Saamns remind me of Pundarikaksha(beautiful lotus petal like eyes of lord).

The problem with Delightful video is annoying background noise and I think chanting is incomplete or specifically Sri Rudram is chanted.

What I need is Purusha Suktam(some details about [Saamveda Purusha Suktam](http://www.ibiblio.org/sripedia/oppiliappan/archives/jun07/msg00094.html)), Sri Suktam, etc in Saamaveda Chanting format.

Answer (score 1):

OM namaH sAmavedAya

I am currently asking about where to find the text of some of the chants that you are asking for: [Three questions about the sAmaveda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44930/three-questions-about-the-samaveda).

[puruShasUkta from sAmaveda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CsAvqXCn9k) The short text is found in this question:
[How is Purusha Sukta revealed in Samaveda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31878/how-is-purusha-sukta-revealed-in-samaveda/33751#33751). The text that you will need for chanting is found [here](https://archive.org/details/SamavedaKouthumaSamhitaGana/page/n397/mode/2up)

[SrI sUktam from sAmaveda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5mm2tSZo0g)

I have also found more general resources for the sAmaveda.[The gAna text for poorvArchika and AraNyakhAnda](https://archive.org/details/SamavedaKouthumaSamhitaGana/) is used for performance, and the [complete base text of the sAmaveda with a long introduction](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/samaveda_kauthuma.pdf) might be useful in chanting as well. You can enjoy listening to the [complete audio](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtPBR-KypqiHlN_7TI2TcYJAfOKgWMm7j). The [romanised text](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/corpustei/transformations/html/sa_sAmavedasaMhitA.htm), [English translation](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sv.htm) and [index of passages from Rigveda](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.180573/page/n367/mode/2up) are helpful when you start learning. To start off, here is [a shorter](http://lakshminarayanlenasia.com/articles/Sama_Veda.pdf) and [longer](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/books/SamaVeda-AnIntroduction.pdf) introduction to the sAmaveda. You should read this first if you are new to chanting.

Comment: Welcome to HSE! It’s a really nice answer. +1 :) Purusha Suktam of the Saamaveda. While you’re browsing the site, you might want to get to know about the functioning and so as far as answering goes you can read the help centre on how to answer as well as [Guidelines for New Users answering](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions). Also you may have a talk with our moderator, TheLittleNaruto in the [Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) for a proper understanding on the type of questions on topic etc.

Comment: Read [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) - have a look at the needs focus part (too many unrelated questions in one question). Hope to see you becoming an active and knowledgeable user :)

Comment: Thank you for this information!