# How is Purusha Sukta revealed in Samaveda?

Tags: vedas, sama-veda

Where does Purusha Sukta appear in Samaveda?

Answer (score 3):

Compared to its Ṛg-vedic counterpart which has 16 verses, Puruṣa-sūkta of Sāma-veda has only 5 verses. Those verses (617-621<sup>§</sup>), from [GRETIL](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/1_veda/1_sam/samavedu.htm):

> REFERENCE SYSTEM: 
>   ārcika | prapāṭhaka | ardha | daśati | verse | line 
>   1 1 1 01 01 a
>
> ---
>
> 2 0 0 0403a sahasraśīrṣā puruṣaḥ sahasrākṣaḥ sahasrapāt . 
>   2 0 0 0403c sa bhūmiṃ sarvato vṛtvātyatiṣṭhaddaśāṅgulam .. 617
>
> 2 0 0 0404a tripādūrdhva udaitpuruṣaḥ pado 'syehābhavatpunaḥ . 
>   2 0 0 0404c tathā viṣvaṅ vyakrāmadaśanānaśane abhi .. 618
>
> 2 0 0 0405a puruṣa evedaṃ sarvaṃ yadbhūtaṃ yacca bhāvyam . 
>   2 0 0 0405c pādo 'sya sarvā bhūtāni tripādasyāmṛtaṃ divi .. 619
>
> 2 0 0 0406a tāvānasya mahimā tato jyāyāṃśca pūruṣaḥ . 
>   2 0 0 0406c utāmṛtatvasyeśāno yadannenātirohati .. 620
>
> 2 0 0 0407a tato virāḍajāyata virājo adhi pūruṣaḥ . 
>   2 0 0 0407c sa jāto atyaricyata paścādbhūmimatho puraḥ .. 621

The index available [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1Fcp4QS2TSCWS1vVXF3ODVGd2c/edit) (pg. 19 of 57) lists the ṛṣis for those mantras (transliteration mine):

```
+------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+
| Sāma-veda  |  Devatā  |  Chanda  |   Svara    |     Ṛṣi           |
| (mantra #) |          |          |            |                   |
+------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+
| 617        | Puruṣaḥ  | anuṣtubh | gāndhāraḥ  | Nārāyaṇaḥ         |
| 618        | Puruṣaḥ  | anuṣtubh | gāndhāraḥ  | Vāmadevo Gautamaḥ |
| 619        | Puruṣaḥ  | anuṣtubh | gāndhāraḥ  | Vāmadevo Gautamaḥ |
| 620        | Puruṣaḥ  | anuṣtubh | gāndhāraḥ  | Vāmadevo Gautamaḥ |
| 621        | Puruṣaḥ  | anuṣtubh | gāndhāraḥ  | Nārāyaṇaḥ         |
+------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+
```

[This](https://archive.org/stream/SamVeda/sam-ved-3-of-7#page/n57/mode/2up) translation by Ārya Samāj however says the ṛṣi for all five verses is Nārāyaṇa.

---

[R. L. Kashyap](http://vedah.com/rlk/) provides some interesting details in his commentary/translation of those verses in [*Essentials of Sāma Veda and its Music*](http://vedah.com/product/essentials-of-sama-veda/):

> **31. Puruṣha Sūkta (5 Mantrās)**
>
> Next to the Gāyatri mantra, Puruṣha Sūkta is the most widely known
>   Sūkta in all 4 Vedās. The version in Rig Veda has 16 mantrās (10.90.1)
>   – (10.90.16). The versions in the Taittirīya Āranyaka and Vājasaneya Samhita have more mantrās. For more details and the text of all these
>   mantrās with their translation, see the compact SAKSI books [Veda
>   Mantrās and Sūktās Widely Used in Worship](http://vedah.com/product/veda-mantra-s-and-sukta-s-widely-used-worship/) and [Puruṣha Sūkta](http://vedah.com/product/purusha-sukta-mantra-s-with-meaning/) by
>   Prof. S. K. Ramachandra Rao.
>
> **The version in Sāma Veda has 5 mantrās only (617) - (621)**.
>
> 617, 618, 621 are almost identical to RV (10.90.1), (10.90.4) and
>   (10.90.5) respectively.
>
> 619 and 620 together represent RV (10.90.2) and RV (10.90.3). SV
>   (619) has first half of (10.90.2) and second half of (10.90.3). SV (620) has the remaining 2 halves.
>
> Puruṣha Sāma, the Sāmagāna, uses these five mantrās and one other
>   mantra devoted to Viṣhṇu. For the text, see the SAKSI book, [Sāma
>   Veda: Pūrva Archika](http://vedah.com/product/sama-veda-purva-archika/), pp. 227-231.
>
> **SV (617): The Thousand-Headed Person**
>
> Puruṣha has numerous heads (1),
>  numerous eyes and feet (2);
>  He
>   pervades the earth on all sides (3),
>  He exists beyond the ten
>   directions (4). (RV 10.90.1)
>
> **SV (618): Inanimate and Animate**
>
> Puruṣha ascended, the three planes (1), 
>  the other part was here
>   again and again (2),
>  From here on all sides He pervades all (3),
>   what is animate and what is not (or Heaven and Earth) (4). (RV
>   10.90.4)
>
> [There is a difference between RV (10.90.4) and SV (618) regarding the
>   pāda (4). The meaning of the phrase *ashana* *anashane* in SV (618) is
>   straightforward. However, RV (10.90.4) has *sāshana* instead of *ashana*.
>   The interpretation of *sāshana* poses difficulties. For more details,
>   see the SAKSI book, [Puruṣha Sūkta](http://vedah.com/product/purusha-sukta-mantra-s-with-meaning/) by Professor S. K. Ramachandra
>   Rao.]
>
> **SV (619): He is All**
>
> Puruṣha, indeed, is all this (universe) (1),
>   what has been and what
>   is to come (2).
>  All beings are a part of Him (3),
>  Three parts (of Him)
>   are immortal in Heaven (4). (RV 10.90.2,3)
>
> **SV (620): Universe is only a small part of Him**
>
> Such is his magnificence (1),
>  but Puruṣha is greater than this
>   (manifestation) (2);
>  He, the Lord of immortality (3),
>  rises
>   (or transcends) from the plane of matter (*anna*) (to higher planes)
>   (4).
>
> **SV (621): Virāṭ**
>
> From him was Virāṭ born, and (1),
>  from Virāṭ was born Puruṣha (the
>   various beings) (2);
>  Born, He spread over (3),
>  the earth from
>   behind and in front (4). (RV 10.90.5)

---

<sup>§</sup> Kashyap on the structure of Sāma-veda:

> A unique feature of the Sāma Veda Samhita (SV) is that every mantra in it has a unique number mentioned usually to the left of the text. The number runs from one to 1875.
>
> The text of the 1875 mantrās of Sāma Veda (*yoni*) mantrās is in 2 chapters, namely, Pūrva Archika and Uttara Archika; they have different structures.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in the answer by user "sv." is correct and useful, but I have some more information about this sAma-sUkta. Below is the full text, but first with svarA marks showing the notes to be sung on, and then the gAna text, an expanded version that is used in performance and ceremonies and has vowel patterns like "uhavAhAu" added. The gAna text is taken from [here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.344932/page/n331/mode/2up) and can also be found [here in clearer to read type](https://archive.org/details/SamavedaKouthumaSamhitaGana/page/n397/mode/2up), and the text with just svarAs is from [this pdf](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_veda/samaveda_kauthuma.pdf).

Here is the svarA text:

[image]
[image]

sAman 617 gAna:

[image]

sAman 618 gAna:

[image]
[image]

sAman 619 gAna:

[image]

sAman 620 gAna:

[image]
[image]

sAman 621 gAna:

[image]

Here is a recording of [puruShasUkta from sAmaveda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CsAvqXCn9k).