# How is the SrIsUktam revealed in the sAmaveda?

Tags: resource, sama-veda

OM namaH sAmavedAya

As this post describes, a form of the puruShasUkta is found in the sAmaveda, [How is Purusha Sukta revealed in Samaveda?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31878/how-is-purusha-sukta-revealed-in-samaveda/33751#33751). [Malola Kannan has also recited SrI sUktam from sAmaveda](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5mm2tSZo0g), but I cannot find the text of this. **How is the SrIsUktam revealed in the sAmaveda?**

I have now answered these two questions by myself:

[This page](http://lakshminarayanlenasia.com/articles/Sama_Veda.pdf) is correct in saying that:

> The basic text is expanded by adding new vowels, modifying some syllables and adding numerals at various points to denote the time duration and singing of those syllables. This version is called as gana and found only in books specialising in Samaveda singing.

This gAna text is the one performed like in the video above: see more examples of it on the pdf guide. It is very important for those who want to recite the sAmaveda traditionally. [This book contains the gAna text for the first half](https://archive.org/details/SamavedaKouthumaSamhitaGana). It seems to go up to sAman #640, out of 1875 total. It has the poorvArchika (585 sAmans) and AraNyakhAnda (55 sAmans).  **Where can the rest of the gAna text for the sAmaveda be found? This would contain mahAnAmnyArchikA and uttarArchikA**, or sAmans #641-1875. There are many places where the basic sAmaveda text is found, but it is very hard to find the gAna.

My final question is shorter: **what are some prayers to say before reciting the sAmaveda?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now found the answers to two of the three questions above.

**[Here is the gana text of the uttarArchikA](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.20603). It is in easy-to-read Devanagari, and [here](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.344932/page/n381/mode/2up) is a similar text of the mahAnAmnyArcikA.** The series of volumes that the second one comes from contains the rest of the sAmaveda, but volume 3 seems to be wrongly uploaded and duplicated.

A prayer to say before reciting the sAmaveda comes from the bRRihadAraNyaka upaniShad 5.13.3. This is so important because it gives the purport of sAmaveda recitation.

> prANo vai sAma, prANe hImAni sarvANi bhUtAni samya~nchi; samya~nchi hAsmai sarvANi bhUtAni, shraiShThyAya kalpante, sAmnaH sAyujyaM salokatAM jayati, ya evaM veda
>
> Verily, breath is the Saman, for all these beings meet in breath. For him who knows this, all beings meet to procure his excellence ; he obtains union and oneness with the Saman.

Along with a similar text (bRRihadAraNyaka upaniShad 1.3.22), this is a good meditation before reciting:

> ashnute sAmnaH sAyujyaM salokatAm ya evametatsAma veda
>
> He who knows this Saman attains union with it, or lives in the same world as it.